# Display Facebook login data on multiple UIViews

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, storyboard

This might be a simple solution, but I'm not really sure how to approach this as of right now.

Simply put, what I want to do is have the data that is pulled from a users Facebook account (where they were prompted to sign in upon opening the app) to be shown later in the main app under a view called Profile. I just want to have this Profile view which is under settings to display the FB profile picture, name, email, and the logout button like the FB tutorial shows. Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into Parse.

Parse makes it really easy to handle all backend services.
A lot of example code and tutorials are to be found here:
https://www.parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios
and here
http://www.raywenderlich.com/44640/integrating-facebook-and-parse-tutorial-part-1